# Unable to push to dcr

Tags: docker, gcloud, docker-registry

unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication

Answer (score 0):

Authenticate your gcloud cli using:

```
gcloud auth login
```

Then update your docker configs:

```
gcloud auth configure-docker
```